# orbeon form builder breaking when adding a new from

Tags: forms, oracle, glassfish, builder, orbeon

I am running Orbeon Forms dev-post-3.7.1.200910140016 on glassfish/oracle . When i am adding a new from (using form edit source ) the from builder is breaking . here is the error i see in log files 
0:20:26,179  INFO DatabaseContext,httpSSLWorkerThread-8888-3:133 - Rolling back JDBC connection for datasource: jdbc/oracle.
10:20:26,192 ERROR ProcessorService,httpSSLWorkerThread-8888-3:105 - Exception at 
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
```

when i add and save  the from it is saved in ORBEON_FORM_DATA table. Adding new row to the table breaks the form builder . any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to first upgrade to the last release of Orbeon Forms, which at the time of this writing is 3.9, release in May 2011. (The version you have there, 3.7.1, was release almost 3 years ago.) Then, if you still have this problem with the latest release, you might want to update your question or post a new question with instructions on how to reproduce it.